# Display challenges after Ubuntu 12.04 updates

Tags: 12.04, updates, display, unity-dash

first posting to this board and a newish Linux user.

I am running Ubuntu Version 12.04 LTS via Virtual Box version 4.3.12 r93733. It just went through a series of updates and after restarting my Dash icons and a few other graphics are messed up. Dash icons are appearing grey with lines through them (basically unreadable) and terminal window is whited out.

Any suggestions? screenshot [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVm2C.png):

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating VirtualBox and re-installing the guest additions drivers.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I have tried that - same issue is sticking. Unfortunately the messed up display also messes up the terminal window making it totally unreadable which is hampering troubleshooting!

Comment: I have tried uninstalling the guest additions iso then reinstalling via software center. Clicking on Virtual box>devices>insert guest additions cd, its looking for the ISO under C:\Program Files\Oracle VM VirtualBox - the downloaded ISO is not there. There is a virtual box folder though here: /var/cache/apt/archives/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso_4.1.12-1_all.deb

So do I need to move this file to the or get virtual box to look in the right directory or...? Keeping in mind my terminal window is not workable.

Thanks again for any advice, Im bumbling my way through this!

Comment: The file needs to be visible to VirtualBox on Windows. It should be automatic, when you select "Insert Guest Additions CD image" VirtualBox will download the ISO file and mount it. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html